# split terminal into different tabs

Tags: bash, shell, tabs, genome

I'm using this script shell to run multiple commands, my problem is that each result of the command appears in a different window, my goal is to have one window with different tabs.

here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "java -jar SBM.jar" >/tmp/ma_commande 
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c ". /tmp/ma_commande;read" ' -t "Building Manager"
rm /tmp/ma_commande

echo "java -jar UserAgent.jar" >/tmp/ma_commande
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c ". /tmp/ma_commande;read" '  -t "User Agent"
rm /tmp/ma_commande 

echo "java -jar PSM.jar" >/tmp/ma_commande
gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c ". /tmp/ma_commande;read"' -t "PSM"
rm /tmp/ma_commande
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use these apps to split terminal window as you wish on Linux or Unix:

**byobu**: http://byobu.co/

**screen**: https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/

these are window manager and the more modern Tmux terminal multiplexer, and works on most Linux, BSD, and Mac distributions